# Boldmath in section title but not in header

Tags: header-footer, scrlayer-scrpage, section-titles, boldmath

I am using the `\boldmath` command for bold math symbols in my section titles. Moreover, I use the `scrlayer-scrpage` package to write the section titles in the header. The problem is that the math symbols are in bold type also in the headers. Is there a way to prevent this?

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt, twoside]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{nameref}

\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearpairofpagestyles

\chead{\headmark}
\automark[section]{section}
\automark*[subsection]{}
\cfoot{\pagemark}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
    
    \section{I want {\boldmath$x$} in bold type}
    
    \subsection{Or Greek letters {\boldmath$\alpha$}}
    
    \Blindtext
    
    \subsection{Another Greek letter {\boldmath$\beta$}}

    \Blindtext
    
    \subsection{And a third one: {\boldmath$\gamma$}}
    
    \blindtext

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Not that it helps but: Are you sure you want the bold math in the section title? What if you have `v = \lvert\mathbf{v}\rvert$` for example, how should that be done in the section title? Should both `v` become bold?

Comment: Yes, it is-. A section title you can write as `\section[<in header and Toc>]{<in text>}`,  i.e. just: write `\section[I want $x$ in normal font]{I want {\boldmath$x$} in bold type}`.

Comment: avoid puttig _any_ formatting in section titles, choice to use bold math is a document level choice, specify \boldmath along with \bfseries while setting up the heading style.

Comment: Have you tried `\subsection[Or Greek letters $\alpha$]{Or Greek letters \boldmath$\alpha$}`?

Comment: @ Zarko and Mico: I have tried this, but this only prevents bold type in the table of contents.

Comment: @ David Carlisle: Could you perhaps explain this in more detail? Do I have to change the command \bfseries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[How to make mathematics bold in headings](https://sourceforge.net/p/koma-script/wiki-en/HowTo_HeadingsBoldMath/) in the KOMA-Script wiki suggests, e.g.,

```
\documentclass[10pt, twoside]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{nameref}% Note: You don't need this, because you are using hyperref.

\pagestyle{scrheadings}% Note: Not needed, because default after loading scrlayer-scrpage
\clearpairofpagestyles

\chead{\headmark}
\automark[section]{section}% Note: Option automark would be an alternative.
\automark*[subsection]{}
\cfoot{\pagemark}% Note: I would recommend to use \cfoot*{\pagemark}. Otherwise the plain pages would be without pagination.

\addtokomafont{disposition}{\boldmath}% add \boldmath to all headings

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\section{I want $x$ in bold type}

\subsection{Or Greek letters $\alpha$}

\Blindtext

\subsection{Another Greek letter $\beta$}

\Blindtext

\subsection{And a third one: $\gamma$}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

But it also explains many other alternatives and why adding `\boldmath` would not help in all cases, e.g., for `\sum`.

Comment: How nice! Thank you!